# Laravel Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::style()`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using the laravel 5.1 framework on my centos6 host. I already used composer install `illuminate/html`, but calling `HTML::style()` results in this error: `FatalErrorException in 7b06fa36a7460c71e5daf57645a3dbda line 12: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::style()`

My app config :

```
'aliases' => [
    //more...
    'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class
],

'providers' => [
    //more...
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
]
```

composer.json:

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*"
},
```

Such as  `{!! Form::open() !!} ...` is well except `HTML::style()`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You have aliased invalid class.

Replace

```
'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

with

```
'HTML' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: I am following a tutorial and this is already how it is in the tutorial, yet I get an error. My specific error is a call to the bindShared method.

Answer (score 5):

terminal

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2.0"
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
  'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: Yes, when installing the dependency composer did mention that the illuminate package was no longer in use and I ran the install again with the _laravelcollective/html_ alternative, which itself is also said to be offline in favor of the _spatie/laravel-html_ package (which strictly wants PHP8 thus is not an option for me right now). Sadly, the tutorial I am following did not highlight how the service provider would change and this is it, nothing more! Thanks Lara Gallassi, and @John Smith. [RTFM](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)!

Answer (score 1):

If using Laravel 5 these have been moved and are now depreciated, and are no longer in the core.
They are now part of the Laravel Collective
Read here for what you should be using, and how to intall

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html